# how to convert an Array to a hot Observable

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

so I have an array that will change over time in size and would like to convert to a hot stream.

tried with no luck:

```
const array = [10, 20, 30];
        const result = from(array, asyncScheduler);
        result.subscribe(x => {
            console.log(x);
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            array.push('waiting for me');
        }, 6000);
```

as 'waiting for me' never gets consoled after 6 sec.
tried also `share()` with no avail

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a subject !

```
const subject$ = new Subject();
subject$.subscribe((x) => {
  console.log(x);
});

[10, 20, 30].forEach((v) => subject$.next(v));

setTimeout(() => {
  subject$.next('waiting for me');
}, 6000);
```

NB: You need to subscribe before pushing, because the values will be sent synchronously in the particular case.

---

or you can also merge 2 streams :

```
const subject$ = new Subject();

const array = [10, 20, 30];
const result = from(array);

setTimeout(() => {
  subject$.next('waiting for me');
}, 6000);


merge(result, subject$).subscribe((x) => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: thank you, yes I am aware of subject but was wondering if there was a way to convert the cold array to just hot... guess not, tx for answer.

Comment: @NarenMurali No offense taken, we're all here to learn !